# Google maps won't load, crashes the whole app

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I still have not solved this one yet.

I've worked with google maps in a few projects, both in Objective C and Swift 2 and iOS 9. I install it using cocoa pods and it works just fine but now, in this app where I'm also using parse and a four square API (not sure if that has anything to do with it) the map view won't even load and the app crashes when I try to.

This is the error I get...

-[GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe51cb3bfb0

It breaks on the line that sets the map view frame, I've tried adding the Obj-C linker flag too (which I've heard could be a possible solution) but that gives me 32 different errors itself.

Can anyone help with this? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I have experience with Google Maps in Swift, but here's some Obj-C code to work off of.  First make sure your GMSMapView delegate is set to self and that you are setting the constraints in your viewDidLoad.  I ran this in various spots:

```
- (void)setBounds
{
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self.currentLocation coordinate];

CGFloat coordinateDifference = 0.002;

CGFloat firstLatitude = coordinate.latitude;
firstLatitude += coordinateDifference;

CGFloat firstLongitude = coordinate.longitude;
firstLongitude += coordinateDifference;

CLLocationDegrees topLat = firstLatitude;
CLLocationDegrees topLon = firstLongitude;
CLLocationCoordinate2D northEastCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(topLat, topLon);

CGFloat secondLatitude = coordinate.latitude;
secondLatitude -= coordinateDifference;

CGFloat secondLongitude = coordinate.longitude;
secondLongitude -= coordinateDifference;

CLLocationDegrees botLat = secondLatitude;
CLLocationDegrees botLon = secondLongitude;
CLLocationCoordinate2D southWestCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(botLat, botLon);

self.bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] init];
self.bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:northEastCoordinate coordinate:southWestCoordinate];
}

- (void)createMap
{
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self.currentLocation coordinate];
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude zoom:17];

CGFloat h = self.topLayoutGuide.length;
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, h, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height - self.postSongButton.frame.size.height - 20);
self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:rect camera:camera];

[self.view insertSubview:self.mapView atIndex:0];
}
```